# how to pass the com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.ReviewPermissionsActivity screen with Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

I'm trying to learn Appium and I'm trying to do some basic stuff over here.
Here is my environment configuration.

- ```
  java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)I have a separate Java 8 installation so that uiautomatorviewer.bat works
  ```
- ```
  Appium version 1.22.3
  ```
- ```
  Node v20.0.0
  ```
- ```
  Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
  ```
- ```
  Android EmulatorPixel 2XLAndroid 13.0
  ```
- ```
  Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
  ```

I'm trying to work with this apk https://github.com/appium-boneyard/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/apps/ApiDemos/bin/ApiDemos-debug.apk

So I have created a base class in which I'm initializing the driver

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;

public class base {

    // permission controller package and activity
    static String PermissionControllerPackage = "com.google.android.permissioncontroller";
    static String PermissionControllerActivity = "com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.ReviewPermissionsActivity";

    public static AppiumDriver options() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {

        File appDir = new File("src");
        File app = new File(appDir, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");
        URL localURL = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub").toURL();

        UiAutomator2Options capabilities = new UiAutomator2Options();
        AppiumDriver driver = null;
        capabilities.setPlatformName("Android");
        capabilities.setDeviceName("Emulator");
        capabilities.setApp(app.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new AppiumDriver(localURL, capabilities);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void allowAppPermissionController() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {

        UiAutomator2Options capabilities = new UiAutomator2Options();
        AppiumDriver driver = null;
        capabilities.setPlatformName("Android");
        capabilities.setDeviceName("Emulator");
        capabilities.setAppPackage(PermissionControllerPackage);
        capabilities.setAppActivity(PermissionControllerActivity);
        URL localURL = new URI("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub").toURL();
        
        driver = new AppiumDriver(localURL, capabilities);
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text = 'Continue']")).click();
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

and I have this basics class in which I'm trying to do some simple automations

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.Duration;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;


public class basics extends base{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        AppiumDriver driver = options();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        allowAppPermissionController();

    }

}
```

When I execute the program, the app opens, but I'm getting stuck in this screen.
[image]

This is what the Appium log is showing:

```
**[debug] [ADB] Found package: 'com.google.android.permissioncontroller' and fully qualified activity name : 'com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.ReviewPermissionsActivity'
[debug] [ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.**
```

If I understand that correctly, the issue is that the driver is initialized for the other app and cannot perform actions on the permission's screen.

I have tried to modify the capabilities during execution, but after googling around it doesn't seem to be possible

I also tried to initialize a new driver just for the com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.ReviewPermissionsActivity screen, but the results are the same.

I also tried

`capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true)`

The solution seems obvious to me, but I have no idea how to accomplish it. Change the focus of the driver to com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.ReviewPermissionsActivity then click "Accept" finally return the focus to the previous app, but I haven't found a way to do such.

If anyone has any ideas it will be highly appreciated